# Histogram with moving parts d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graphics

I really like this graphic by nytimes. Its has squares as moving parts and really nice transitions. I was wondering if its possible to do something similar with d3.js? Not sure if its already done in d3 but I haven’t found any related example online.

[Here is the link to the article](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2016/04/05/us/elections/state-voter-histograms.html?ref=politics) 
 [image: NYtimes election histogram]

Comment: It is totally possible to implement this with `d3.js`, but you'll probably be spending time figuring out the algorithm and state management for the movements.

Comment: @Kujira : would be really helpful if you can  share with me an example close to this one?

Comment: I couldn't find good examples relevant to this chart. Rather than a chart, try thinking it as bunch of boxes moving to specific location without colliding with each other. `d3.js` is all about creating custom charts rather than drag-n-drop, so good luck!